# Different shapes between new data and training dataset

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, classification, shapes

I have a dataframe and looks something like the one below.

```
    Spent      Products bought         Target Variable               
0   2300       Car/Mortgage/Leisure    0
1   1500       Car/Education           0
2   150        Groceries               1
3   700        Groceries/Education     1  
4   900        Mortgage                1
5   180        Education/Sports        1
6   1800       Car/Mortgage/Others     0
7   900        Sports/Groceries        1
8   1000       Self-Enrichment/Car     1
9   140        Car/Groceries           1
```

I used `pd.get_dummies` to one hot encode all the "products bought" column. **Now I have a shape of (5000,150)**.

I train/test/split my data and thereafter, applied PCA. I `fit_transform` the train set, and applied only `transform` on the test set. Following that I used a decision tree classifier to predict which got me a 90% accuracy.

Now here comes the problem. I have new set of data. I **know my model was trained on a shape of (,150) and this **new data only has a shape of (150, 28)** after** applying encoding with `pd.get_dummies`.

I know merging the new data with the old dataset is not a solution. I'm kind of stuck, and I'm not sure how to go about solving this. Anyone has any input? Thanks

Edit: I tried reindexing the new dataset but it did not work. There are more unique variables in the "products bought" column my training set and less so in my new dataset.

The new dataframe looks more like something like the one below.

```
    Spent      Products bought         Target Variable               
0   230        Leisure                 1
1   150        Others                  1
2   100        Groceries               1
3   700        Education               1  
4   900        Mortgage                0
5   180        Education/Sports        1
6   1800       Car/Mortgage            0
7   400        Groceries               1
8   4000       Car                     1
9   140        Car/Groceries           1
```

Comment: try `pd.get_dummies().reindex(train.columns, axis=1)`?

Comment: u mean on the new dataset? or on the old one?

Comment: on the new dataset. `reindex` assure that you have the same columns, in the same ordering with the `train` dataset.

Comment: just tried it but it returned what i expected which was "Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 150 and input n_features is 28"

Comment: Because my data is trained on 150 inputs, and when the new data came in, after encoding it only has 28 features.. so yea i'm not sure how to deal with it

Comment: `train.columns` must be your train set's columns (150). Otherwise, you should check out one hot encoder.